# Cannot find bin folder after installing MongoDB 3.6 for OSX Yosemite

Tags: mongodb, macos, osx-yosemite

I would like to use MongoDB on my Mac (OSX Yosemite), but after installing version 3.6 I can start MongoDB, but I'm not able to use Mongo shell. After checking the directories I also cannot find bin folder inside MongoDB folder.

I can only start MongoDB with: 
brew services start mongodb-community@3.6

==> Successfully started `mongodb-community@3.6` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-c

I can't use 3.6 because my xCode is too old for this version.

brew info mongodb
mongodb: stable 4.0.3
High-performance, schema-free, document-oriented database
https://www.mongodb.com/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mongodb.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: go ✘, pkg-config ✔, scons ✘
Required: openssl ✘, python@2 ✘
==> Requirements
Build: xcode ✘

Thank you guys in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to search for it by "find / -iname 'mongo'"

Mine is at below two places:

- /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Aliases/mongo
- /Users//mongodb/mongodb-osx-x86_64-enterprise-4.0.4/bin/mongo